# How to compare file names in directory with file names in a text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-xp

I try to improve an overview of my search and find memories for batch files in Windows XP command prompt environment.
In order to my previous sentence I am not happy with my search possibilities and have to post a question.

I try to compare the names of some text files and have written words in a text file that are by reading the same. With such a start environment I wrote following batch script to get an echo output.

The aim is

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir "C:\A Folder"') do set var=%%~nb & echo !var!

rem   The output is the name of the files without extension. Now my question:
rem   Is it possible to compare the above file names with some input
rem   from a text file, for example like:

for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir "C:\A Folder"') do set var=%%~nb & for /f %%a in (Textfile.txt) do (if !var!==%%a echo good else echo search)

rem   That returns no output. I would like to know if there are possibilities
rem   to do that? And if it is possible, how to revise this batch file?

endlocal disabledelayedexpansion
pause
```

Have a nice day, wishes
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with Latin characters - some foreign characters may not work:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d "C:\A Folder\*.*" ') do find /i "%%~nb" < "textfile.txt" >nul && (echo "%%~nb" found) || (echo "%%~nb" not found)

pause
```

Comment: I would use `findstr /x` instead of just `find`

Comment: @Stephan You'd also need to use `/c` because the term can contain spaces, but they will both work.

Comment: For this code i turned the /a-d parameter form the dir command blank, therefor a name of a folder was shown and it was possible to show a difference. The output showed found for every compared listed name and not found for the folder name that was not on the list saved.

Comment: I don't have your text file or the contents of your folder, so I have no idea what you are comparing.

Answer (score 0):

proper formatting you code increases readabilty:

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d "C:\A Folder"') do (
  for /f %%a in (textfile.txt) do (
    if "%%~nb"=="%%a" ( echo good ) else ( echo search )
  )
)
```

I added a `/b` to the `dir`command (show name only, no date/time/attributes) and a `/a-d` to exclude directorynames.

You don't need to use a variable (`!var!`) here (but you can, it works fine).

Comment: Stephan, your code will return a result for every line in the textfile, and ditto for every filename, right?  Spaces will be a problem too.

Comment: @foxidrive: yes, that's what I understood from OP's `if !var!==%%a echo good else echo search`. And you are right with the spaces - I'll correct this.

Comment: I tried the above one first, for code Test i used the dir command output and it worked fine. When i tried the rest of the code too, it returned for the list with sixteen names, fifteen times the compare output of the same list with sixteen search and one good.